# Split multiple separators

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that contains urls separate by | like this:

`http://...|http://...|http://...`

but inside some urls I may have the caracheter **|**, so I could split it with .split("|http://") but the problem is that inside some urls contains another urls like this

`http://...|http://..=http://...=http://...|http://...=http%25253A%25252F%25252F...`

So how can I split by `|http:// or =http:// or =http%25253A%25252F%25252F`  using regex?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
String str = "http://www.google.com|https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301982|http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split.htm";
String delimiters = "\\|(?=http)";

// analyzing the string 
String[] urls = str.split(delimiters);

// prints the number of tokens
System.out.println("Count of urls= " + urls.length);

for(String url: urls) {
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

It will split on `|` followed by `http`. The output for this sample is:

```
Count of urls = 3
http://www.google.com
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301982
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
// As your question in this string contains three https
String httpStr = "http://...|http://..=http://...=http://...|http://...=http%25253A%25252F%25252F...";
// Split the string with 'http' that preceded by |
String[] https = httpStr.split("(?<=\\|)http");
for (String http : https) {
    System.out.println("http = http" + http);
}
```

And it is the result:

```
http = http://...|
http = http://..=http://...=http://...|
http = http://...=http%25253A%25252F%25252F...
```